# I can not use Angular material in my project

Tags: angular, angular-material

While using Angular. I am getting following error while using material. Please help me out: these are the errors that i am getting in my terminal

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js 1478:59-77
>       "export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"angular-datatables": "^7.0.0",
"cleave.js": "^1.5.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
"datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
"jquery": "^3.4.0",
"ngx-cleave-directive": "^1.0.6",
"ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"sweetalert2": "^8.11.7",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
```

Comment: You're using material and cdk version 8.1.1 with angular 7.2.15. Think about getting your versions in sync. Maybe install material and cdk to version 7.3.7, or 7.2.2, rather than 8.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

`defineInjectable` and `inject` have been part of compiled Angular code since **v6**, to support `tree-shakeable` providers.

Recently, `defineInjectable` was renamed to `ɵɵdefineInjectable` and `defineInjectable` was deprecated. 
This makes pre-8 libraries compatible with v8, however v8 compiled libraries will not be compatible with pre-8 consumers.

If you want your library to be consumable in **v7**, then you must compile with **v7** as well. The reason is that new versions are backwards compatible, but older versions being forward compatible is far harder to achieve.

So update your `@angular/core` to v8 or use v7 for angular.